# socket.io setting for ip on local network

Tags: configuration, socket.io

I have a socket server running on port 8000 on my local machine and it is connected to the router via dhcp

My app runs fine but when i get a different ip from the router I have to change the ip for the include in the script

My router unfortunately doesnt have the ip reservation feature

```
<script src="http://192.168.2.3:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.3:8000');
</script>
```

Is there any way I can get away without hardcoding the path. (I cannot use localhost because if I try to use a different computer it doesn't work then)

Comment: What OS are you running? Not sure about Windows and OSX, but on Linux you can set static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Take a look at [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/)

Comment: I am running ubuntu. I tried this solution but when I give a static ip from the dhcp list, sometimes I get ip conflicts :(

Comment: You may set a wide range of IP addresses on the router, say from `192.168.2.2` to `192.168.2.199`, and assign `192.168.2.199` to your local computer. In this case IP conflicts would be unlikely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from @Curious. I set a range in DHCP and used an IP outside this range.